# Angular Inline-Edit Design

Tags: angular

I have been trying to design an "Inline-Edit" component in Angular.
Following is the design and the use cases

```html
<toggle-editor>
  <toggle-normal></toggle-normal>
  <toggle-edit></toggle-edit>
</toggle-editor>
```

The idea is that the user can also define **Toggle Editor** without child components

1. toggle-normal
2. toggle-edit

Simply like:

```html
<toggle-editor></toggle-editor>
```

In this case a default templates will be rendered..

```html
<div (click)="toggle()">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<ng-container
  *ngTemplateOutlet="!isEditing && !toggleNormal ? normalTmpl : null"
></ng-container>
<ng-container
  *ngTemplateOutlet="isEditing && !toggleEdit? ? editTmpl : null"
></ng-container>

<ng-template #normalTmpl> Markup for label</ng-template>
<ng-template #editTmpl> Markup for input </ng-template>
```

**TS file :**

```js
import { Component, ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ToggleNormal } from './toggle.normal.component';
import { ToggleEdit } from './toggle.edit.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'toggle-editor',
  templateUrl: './toggle.editor.component.html',
})
export class ToggleEditor {
  isEditing: boolean = false;
  @ContentChild(ToggleNormal) toggleNormal: ToggleNormal;
  @ContentChild(ToggleEdit) toggleEdit: ToggleEdit;

  toggle() {
    this.isEditing = !this.isEditing;
  }
}
```

**Toggle Edit Component TS:**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ToggleEditor } from './toggle.editor.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'toggle-edit',
  template: '<ng-content *ngIf="toggleEditor.isEditing"></ng-content>',
})
export class ToggleEdit {
  constructor(private toggleEditor: ToggleEditor) {}
}
```

As you can see, in this design: `ToggleEditor` has a dependency on `ToggleEdit` and `ToggleEdit` has a dependency on `ToggleEditor` for their own reasons....
So the issue is circular dependencies.

If I don't provide default templates and don't have content child for **ToggleNormal** and **ToggleEdit**, then there won't be any circular dependency but I want to have this design goal of providing default templates.

Not sure how to handle this scenario... ??

Comment: You can use `@Optional` decorator. https://angular.io/api/core/Optional#description

Comment: you can not inject component inside component. You can use service to handle two scenarios.

Comment: @HardikPatel... you can inject a parent component inside a child component... that's not the issue

Comment: you should use @ViewChild. Dependency injection of component is not a good practic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either have the parent import the children or have the children import the parent.  Not both.

If `ToggleEdit` needs to know about the parent, it can set `toggleEditor.hasToggleEdit = true` in the constructor.  Then the `ToggleEditor` can use `hasToggleEdit` to check whether to use the default template or not.

You may run into change detection issues with that method, in which case, you'd need to have `ToggleEdit` call `toggleEditor.registerToggleEdit()` and that function would look like this:

```js
registerToggleEdit() {
  this.hasToggleEdit = true;
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```